# Groovy: this.metaClass Versus instance.metaClass

Tags: groovy, this, metaclass

I have encountered below groovy script code in the book . And it generated some strange outputs to me.

```
class Person{
  def work(){
    println "work()"
  }
  def sports=['basketball','football','voleyball']
  def methodMissing(String name, args){
    if(name in sports){
        println "injected ${name} into Person class"
        Person instance=this
        println "this.metaClass:\t\t${this.metaClass}"
        println "instance.metaClass:\t${instance.metaClass}"
        assert this.metaClass==instance.metaClass
    }else{
        println "no such method:${name}() in Person class"
    }
  }
}
def jack=new Person()
jack.football()
```

it's output is as below:

```
injected football into Person class
this.metaClass:     groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@245b4bdc[class Person]
instance.metaClass: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@245b4bdc[groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@245b4bdc[class Person]]
Caught: Assertion failed: 
//I did not paste the detailed assertion here for simplicity
```

So I am quite confused:

1. why is this.metaClass not equal to instance.metaClass?
2. further more, I can not use this.metaClass to inject new methods; groovy tells me this.metaClass have no such property, which I intended to inject.
3. What does "org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@245b4bdc[groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@245b4bdc[class Person]]" mean? I know "245b4bdc" may be the object pointer. But why HandleMetaClass and MetaClassImpl have the same pointer value "245b4bdc"?

Currently, I figured out that @245b4bdc is not the "**Object reference**", So **HandleMetaClass@245b4bdc** is not necessarily the same instance as **MetaClassImpl@245b4bdc**. We can use Object.is() method to judge whether they are the same.(I did that, result is **false**)

Comment: If you change it to `assert this.class.metaClass == instance.metaClass`, it passes.

Comment: Why? Should this.class.metaClass == Person.metaClass?

Comment: Found a better answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407488/42769, actually, that's me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. why this.metaClass != instance.metaClass?

   It involves groove's access to fields.

   - When accessing an instance field from "**outside**", groovy actually calls the function getFieldName(). In my example, when I use "**instance**", i am at the **outside**; So **instance.metaClass** will call **instance.getMetaClass()**.
   - When accessing an instance field from "**inside**", groovy simply directly access the field, getFieldName() is not called. In our example, when I use "**this**", i am at the "**inside**"; So "**this.metaClass**" will access "**metaClass**" directly.
   - Finally, getMetaClass() returns a **HandleMetaClass** object while the internal metaClass is a **MetaClassImpl** object. So **this.metaClass!=instance.metaClass**.
2. Why this.metaClass.say={->println "say"} will throws MissingPropertyException?

   - this.metaClass's type is MetaClassImpl
   - MetaClassImpl is a low level class, which supports upper level classes(eg. HandleMetaClass) for injection. It's not meant for Developer to use directly, So it does not support the injection way: **xxxx.say={->println "say"}**.

Code Sample(For Question 1):

```
class Person{
  def work(){
    println "work()"
  }
  def sports=['basketball','football','voleyball']
  def methodMissing(String name, args){
    if(name in sports){
        Person instance=this

        println "this.metaClass:\n\t${this.metaClass}"
        println "instance.metaClass:\n\t${instance.metaClass}"
        //output: false
        println "this.metaClass.is(instance.metaClass):\n\t${this.metaClass.is(instance.metaClass)}"

        //output: true
        println "this.getMetaClass().is(instance.getMetaClass()):\n\t${this.getMetaClass().is(instance.getMetaClass())}"

    }else{
        println "no such method:${name}() in Person class"
    }
  }
}
def jack=new Person()
jack.football()
jack.football()
```

Code Sample(For Question 2):

```
class Cat{}
    def a=new groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl(Cat)
try{
    a.say={->println "say"}
}catch(MissingPropertyException e){
    println "[Fail]\n\tcan not inject method say() into MetaClassImpl class.\n"
}

def b=new org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass(a)
println b
b.say={->println "[say]"}
println "[OK]\n\tcan inject method say() into HandleMetaClass class\n"
def method=b.getMetaMethod("say")
method.invoke(this)
```

Comment: So how is it doing field access to `metaClass` when it hasn't been defined in the current class? Perhaps it's access modifier is protected in its `Object` superclass maybe? But in any case, in order to get field access, the property needs to be accessed from within the class that defines it, according to the groovy doc. `metaClass` is not defined in the Person subclass so I wonder how field access is being done.