# Groovy instance.metaclass vs this.metaclass

Tags: gradle, groovy, this, metaprogramming, metaclass

I have a following script:

```
task myTask {}

class Person {

     Person() {
        Person instance = this
        println this.metaClass.class.name
        println this.getMetaClass().class.name
        println instance.metaClass.class.name
        println instance.getMetaClass().class.name
    }
}

Person person = new Person()
```

And the output is :

```
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding the difference between `this.` and `instance.` or `metaClass` and `getMetaClass`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy: this.metaClass Versus instance.metaClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449587/groovy-this-metaclass-versus-instance-metaclass)

Comment: i checked that post and this post is contradicting it ! why instance.metaClass is also different than this.getMetaClass() ?

Comment: This post explains it perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340189/what-is-groovys-metaclass-used-for `instance` is a different metaclass than `this` bascially. It's org.codehaus' version.

Comment: I will check it thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this `class`,

```
class Person {

    def a, b

    Person() {
        a = this
        b = this
        println "this $this"
        println "a $a"
        println "b $b"
    }

    def printAll() {
        println "this.metaClass ${this.metaClass}"
        println "this.class.metaClass ${this.class.metaClass}"
        println "a.metaClass ${a.metaClass}"
        println "b.metaClass ${b.metaClass}"
    }
}
```

[image]

Take a look at the screenshot of the `groovysh`. It might give you a little hint about what's going on.

1. `p` and `q` are two different objects, but
2. `p.metaClass` is the same as `q.metaClass`, and
3. `printAll` prints exactly the same thing for both, `p` and `q`
4. `a.metaClass` and `b.metaClass` are holding `this.class.metaClass`, not `this.metaClass`, you see

There is only one object created of `MetaClassImpl`, and also only one of `HandleMetaClass`, for `Person`. And no matter how many times you instantiate  `Person`, they will be assigned to the instance. But, when you expand any of that instance, only then a new `HandleMetaClass` object will be created -- just for that particular object; and this time `HandleMetaClass` will be holding not `MetaClassImpl`, but `ExpandoMetaClass` instead.

See the screenshot below,

[image]

Now, to answer your question, `this.metaClass` is a special case, like `this` itself. It doesn't give you the handle, `HandleMetaClass` object, so you can't expand over `metaClass` of `this` -- directly; and there is no sense in that either, because then all other future instances will share that expansion.

If you really want that behaviour then you can pass `this` to some other variable, i.e. `instance = this`, as you did in the constructor, and then you can expand over that `instance` -- and that expansion would be true for `this` and all other future instances. But then, why not add the behaviour to class itself, in the first place. Why expand?

Comment: Thank you very much, but i steal don't get how this is different from instance in the block of code of person's constructor. Can you please clarify that  ?

Comment: Thank you very much